# Is there a way to write a function that accepts a string as an argument then separates the string

Tags: dart, join, split

The purpose is to write a function that accepts a string as an argument then separates the string into chunks of 4 e.g "tgifzero" will return "tgif-zero". **But the rule is the last chunk shouldn't have a dash e.g "tgifzero" will return "tgif-zero" not "tgif-zero-"**. But using the string split method hasn't been helpful enough.

```
void main() {
  print(chunk('234567890123'));
}
String chunk(String string){
  var good = string.split('').join('').replaceRange(6, 6, '-');
  return good;
}
```

I was expecting something like it to divide the string into 4 chunks and also be able to add the dash character.

This is what I got back.
`2345678-90123`

Answer (score 0):

Let's just do the brute-force thing, and not try to be "clever":

```dart
String splitInFours(String input) {
  var result = StringBuffer();
  var cursor = 0;
  while (cursor + 4 < input.length) {
    result..write(input.substring(cursor, cursor + 4))..write("-");
    cursor += 4;
  }
  result.write(input.substring(cursor));
  return result.toString();
}
```

If you *want* to use a RegExp, I'm sure you can, but it's not really worth it for something where the matches are as primitive as "any four characters".

```dart
final _fourCharRE = RegExp(r"[^]{1,4}");
String cleverSplitByFours(String input) => 
   _fourCharRE.allMatches(input).map((m) => m[0]).join("-");
```

It's not going to be more efficient.